# xamarin ios How to cover status bar by navigation bar

Tags: ios, xamarin, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to implement a navigation header which will cover complete header portion including status bar.

Want to change header portion to blue including status bar.

Scenario : When user scrolls page upward, It shows navigation header to user including navigation title.(Which should cover status bar)

Actual Result : I am able to show navigation header but excluding status bar .

Can anyone please help me on this scenario. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the navigation custom or system?  How do you set it to blue color?  Can you attach  your expected result(image) ?

Comment: Navigation is system defined. Setting color by NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 35, 93);.

Comment: I tried your code ,found the color of status bar is the same as navigation bar, what effect are you expecting? Can you attach the demonstrative image?